# Generate vectors given degree of polynomial and list of coeficients

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity, and I'm making a generator in which the user inputs a degree of a polynomial plus all of its coefficients. For example, I can have degree 3 and `[1,2,3,4]`, which should be `1x^3 + 2x^2 + 3x^1 + 4x^0`.
Here's what I have:

```
        int[] coef = TitleToGame.coeficients;
        for (int x = -10; x <= 10; x++)
        {
            float y = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < TitleToGame.degree - 1; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    y = coef[TitleToGame.degree] * Mathf.Pow(x, i);
                }
                else
                {
                    y += coef[TitleToGame.degree - i] * Mathf.Pow(x, i);
                }
                Instantiate(block, new Vector3(x, y, 5), Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
```

I'm trying to generate blocks from domain -10 to 10. However, the result looks a bit funky.

Degree 3 with [1,1,1,1] shows a parabola with an extra linear line:
[image]

Degree 2 shows a linear line (with an extra unwanted flat line), 1 doesn't show anything, and 4 also shows a parabola. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling Instantiate in the inner for loop, when I persume you want to call it in the outer loop (from -10 to 10).

Also, you probably don't need that if-else statement. Both lines do the same thing.

```
for (int i = 0; i < TitleToGame.degree - 1; i++)
{
    y += coef[TitleToGame.degree - i] * Mathf.Pow(x, i);
}
Instantiate(block, new Vector3(x, y, 5), Quaternion.identity);
```